# What's the recommended Bcrypt C implementation?

Tags: c, security, bcrypt

There's at least two Bcrypt implementations in C out there:

- The original: http://bcrypt.sourceforge.net/
- Openwall's: http://www.openwall.com/crypt/

Which one should I use as the basis for a new project?  Note that I have no need for backwards compatibility, so my choice will rest solely on whichever implementation is considered more up-to-date and maintained.  Also, I'm curious which one is used as the base for most non-C language bindings.

Comment: Use whichever suits your needs.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [last release of bcrypt](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bcrypt/files/bcrypt/1.1/) was done back in 2002. The [mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=bcrypt-users) carries just a few messages per year, most of which are never answered. It seems like that project has been dead for quite some time.

[Openwall's latest version](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/), OTOH, was [released in 2011](http://www.openwall.com/lists/announce/2011/07/17/1), so I'd look at that implementation first.

Comment: quiet does not mean "no longer works".

Comment: @gbjbaanb: no, but it often enough means "no longer supported". Unfortunately, the hardware/software environment tends to slip from under systems software unless it is regularly updated.

Comment: Note that the Openwall versions fixed [CVE-2011-2483](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-2483).