# Authentication with bcrypt hashed password

Tags: c++, hash, passwords, authorization, bcrypt

In my C++ application, user must login in order to use the application.
The user login data are taken from phpBB 3.1 database, which uses for password hashing bcrypt. However, I didn't found any suitable example for C++.

So my question is:

How I can auth user with bcrypt hashed password in C++? I know how to do authentication from external database in C++, I just need help with the bcrypt.

Thank you!

Comment: Question #1 is too broad. Question #2 is off-topic.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Thank you for the information, I tried to improve my question best as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BCrypt is really not as common as it could be, but there is a [Stackoverflow question on What's the recommended Bcrypt C implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9977256/1967612) that will point you to [Openwall's crypt_blowfish](http://www.openwall.com/crypt/).

Given a solid C implementation, you need only a wrapper for your C++ code to be good to go!

I would also note that the single most useful Google result is, in fact, this question.  In particular, the Crypto++ library still has BCrypt on their planned features list.

Don't forget to increase the work factor above 12 or 14 when you use it!

Once you have a working implementation, if you'd like to give a reasonable open source license, I'd be happy to include it in [my Github repository](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords?tab=repositories) to provide an alternative to PBKDF2 examples!

Comment: I found this question early on, but it took me longer to find a C++ wrapper. https://github.com/trusch/libbcrypt seems to be doing the trick!