# Comparing password encrypted by bcrypt

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, bcrypt

I have a webpage that encrypts username passwords using bcrypt, these passwords are then stored in a database. I have a c++ program running on QT which needs to authenticate users, in order to do this i'd have to encrypt the user entered password and compare it to the password in the database. Is this the correct way to do it? If so how do i achieve this? The encryption of the user entered password would have to be the same as the one by bcrypt, how do i do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590105/authentication-with-bcrypt-hashed-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Authentication with bcrypt hashed password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590105/authentication-with-bcrypt-hashed-password)

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't encrypt passwords, because they may can be decrypted. The right way of doing it, is to **hash** a password and store the hash value. If a user enters a password you also hash that value and compare it to the saved hash value. This is the right way because a hash function is a one way function (Non-invertible), see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

The hash method prevents that somebody can decrypt the password. You should take care of a secure hash function like SHA-2 or SHA-3, because some hash functions are no longer secure, see [list of broken hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Broken_hash_functions).

Comment: Despite OP is confusing the terms, bcrypt is actually a hashing function.