# How to use bcrypt_gensalt with /dev/urandom on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cng

I used this BCrypt lib to generate a hash with salt: https://github.com/rg3/libbcrypt

The problem is in `bcrypt.c` (`int bcrypt_gensalt`). `open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY)` does not work on Windows. I have tried the following:

```
int bcrypt_gensalt(int factor, char salt[BCRYPT_HASHSIZE]) {
    int fd;
    unsigned char input[RANDBYTES];
    int workf;
    char *aux;

    HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv;

    if (CryptAcquireContext(
        &hCryptProv,
        NULL,
        (LPCSTR)"Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0",
        PROV_RSA_FULL,
        CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) {
        if (CryptGenRandom(
            hCryptProv,
            RANDBYTES,
            input)) {

            if (CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0)) {
                return 0;
            }
            else {
                printf("Error during CryptReleaseContext.\n");
            return 4;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0)) {
                printf("Error during CryptGenRandom.\n");
                return 2;
            }
            else {
                printf("Error during CryptReleaseContext.\n");
                return 3;
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Error during CryptAcquireContext!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Generate salt. */
    workf = (factor < 4 || factor > 31)?12:factor;
    aux = crypt_gensalt_rn("$2a$", workf, input, RANDBYTES,
                   salt, BCRYPT_HASHSIZE);
    return (aux == NULL)?5:0;
}
```

But the result is:

```
Generated salt:
Hashed password: *0
Time taken: 0.000000 seconds
First hash check: OK
Second hash check: OK
First hash check with bcrypt_checkpw: OK
Time taken: 0.060000 seconds
Second hash check with bcrypt_checkpw: OK
Time taken: 0.060000 seconds
```

The salt will be not generated correctly.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35590105/authentication-with-bcrypt-hashed-password helps you.

Comment: Thx, but no. I spent 5 days with google and forums before I asked here^^

Comment: your code and your output don't match up at all....

Comment: You should probably add the code that **(a)** declares the variable you pass in to receive the salt; **(b)** the call to this function and **(c)** how you are printing the returned salt. If not already doing so, you should be printing the return value of this function. More importantly, unless I'm reading it wrong, it looks like the above function will always have returned before it gets to `/* Generate salt. */`...

Comment: @UKMonkey My code is a part of the lib that i wrote above. But i can't generate a salt with lib on windows. Thats my problem^^

Comment: Assuming the `Crypt...` functions return true (non-zero) on success, I'm pretty sure the `return 0`  shouldn't be there:  I'm pretty sure it's causing the function to exit before ever generating the salt.

Comment: I deleted the return under if (CryptReleaseContext(hCryptProv, 0)) {. Now I get an error in bcrypt_hashpw function. So many problems... Maybe it's easier to use PBKDF2. OpenSSL is already included and could use this. What is your opinion?

Comment: Windows does not have `/dev/urandom`; use `CryptGenRandom` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your call to:

```
aux = crypt_gensalt_rn("$2a$", workf, input, RANDBYTES,
                   salt, BCRYPT_HASHSIZE);
```

The values of `RANDBYTES` and `BCRYPT_HASHSIZE` need one more byte for terminated `\0`.

Have you tried that (using `RANDBYTES-1` and `BCRYPT_HASHSIZE-1`)?

Comment: **If** they are null-terninated strings, and not just buffers, the correct change would almost certainly be to increase the buffer size available, not reduce the length of the buffer that you use.

Comment: I tried this now, but then it crashes (   assert(ret == 0);   )

Comment: The function takes the length of the buffer. Decreasing or increasing should have same effect. From the code you posted it is not clear where it crashes. Do you have call stack for it?

Comment: "_Decreasing or increasing should have same effect_" except that I strongly suspect that the sizes are not arbitrary. Even if the `crypt_gensalt_rn()` routine can work with arbitrary size buffers, the system in which this is a part _probably_ requires hashes of a certain size (e.g. 64/128/256 bits; not 56/120/244 bits).

Comment: @TripeHound I agree, in general. But normally it should parse / verify that values are satisfied to required length.

Comment: Thx guys. After so many problem I decided to use PBKDF2. Should I post my PBKDF2 - snippet here as an answer?